# My OBS Video recording is choppy

Tags: kde, manjaro, obs-studio

I use **OBS** only for screen recording. But when I stop recording, I found My video is choppy.

**My System information:**

```
Operating System: Manjaro Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.84.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.10.53-1-MANJARO (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i3-8100 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Memory: 7.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630
```

You can see a screen recording of my computer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9HcUYbnkS8

How can I fix it, can anyone tell me please?

Comment: Offhand, without knowing anything about OBS, I would say you need to use a higher frame rate--It looks like the "choppy" is because a some points, it encoded only a partially drawn video frame without completing before the next frame started.

Comment: Maybe youtube "saved" some bandwidth by dropping a few frames?

Comment: @JeremyBoden No, I always see it even I don't upload to youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with OBS on Fedora Xfce. On XFce I use pavucontrol (pulse audio volume control panel) to control the sound, and I just mute every other source of the recording, when running OBS I've had 3 sources (I only needed one - from Camlink HDMI).

This solved the issue. Here is the screenshot of the panel, where only one source is not muted.

[image: GUI of pavucontrol - Volume Control Panel]